# Clarification about PHP/MySQL Transactions and SELECT FOR UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, pdo, locking

This is my setup:
Table in a MySQL database containing 30-minute time slots (whole and half hour)
A website that shows a table for a period of time how many rooms are available for booking at each time slot.
Minimum booking is one hour so each booking reserves two slots at least and when reserved the slot before them becomes unavailable (cannot book a room for 30 minutes)

My question is this:
I use PDO transactions in a php script to reserve a number of slots for a booking by changing their state (two columns of enum types). So if let's say two or more customer try to book a room at the same time slot or perhaps the one before it what happens if I use SELECT FOR UPDATE? Does the first one continues with the procedure and the others are rejected (by either an error or an empty set) or do the others wait after the first one finishes and commits the changes in the database in the case he booked or rollback in the case he changed his mind and afterwards the second fastest customer tries to selects the rows and updates them or not depending on the actions of the first?

Basically I want to know if I have to implement some sort of retry system.

Also, I was curious when is that temporary lock removed; only after the transaction is committed in case of transactions (both mysql, auto-commit off) or on the next update that affects some/all of the rows in the select statement?

Answer (score -1):

Basically, in PDO, transaction (started with `beginTransaction` method) are just "emulated" by setting autocomit to false.
So, even if the risk of concurrent acces with select to update is tight, it exists.

You can start your transaction with the SQL statement `$db->query('START TRANSACTION')` then `db->query('COMMIT');` or, of course, in case of failure `db->query('ROLLBACK');`
Normally, it will allows you to avoid your problems.
If you want to be sure, you can, inside the transaction, use `$db->query('LOCK TABLE ...');`

When you use Transaction, everything is sent at the same time so that you can't have garbage in your tables.
As every transaction (by default one query is a transaction) is executed one after another, theorically, this protect you against concurent access. But the problem is that you use SELECT to Update and I think there can be edge cases when transaction does not protect you and you will silently delete a good data with another.

Lock tables are usefull for that because no edgecases are allowed. The problem is that if you keep the lock too much time, an error will be sent.

Comment: Did you read the question? He asked what happens when a second user tries to run the script while the first one has the table locked: do they get an error or do they wait for the table to be unlocked.

Comment: Yes, well, my first thought was of locking the table to edit, but it is one big table and I didn't want to lock the table for everyone, just for the rows concerned and that's why I thought the select for update. Also, if I use your method, I should use unlock before commit. Also why this in favor of transactions of pdo. I think you can use pdo transaction and also lock as well, only you use unlock after commit or rollback I think

Comment: Ok, so it is just my answer that is not accurate enough (I read the question of course)...

Comment: No prob, we are all here to learn... well I am, so any new info and/or ideas are appreciated. Maybe I will learn something I didn't know

Comment: transaction and lock are OK together. And it is more sane. THe problem with PDO transaction (with beginTransaction) is that it is not a true transaction whereas using a query 'START TRANSACTION' is OK

Comment: Are beginTransaction and START TRANSACTION different, the way I understood it, they turn autocommit off and then turn it back on... So I guess the only difference would be if pdo does by some other way than mysql commands... Anyone can clarify how one differs from the other. It's no big deal, I just like using as much as I can of the PDO... (quirk of mine regarding uniformity)

Comment: I read again the Mysql documentation and it seems that for mysql it is the same using beginTransaction and START TRANSACTION.
Nevertheless, you can configure your transaction to set a "lock policy" with the SET TRANSACTION synthax http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation.html